# symfony : How to explode schema.yml as fixtures?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, schema.yml

My model is a bit complicated and my schema.yml has many lines. So what I want is to explode schema in many files, in order to make it more readable.

I know, it's possible with the fixtures and my question is : there is a way to do the same thing with schema.yml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just create multiple *.yml files, and their all read. You can even use references across files.